# Proper production implementation of class property getter/setter

Tags: swift, this, production-environment, self

In languages like Java, PHP, Swift, there are keywords like `this`, `$this`, and `self`, respectively, which are reflexive pointers to a particular instance of the containing class. Both Java and Swift allow the programmer to omit this statement entirely if no other local variables share the same identifier. My question is what is the recommended way to write this in production? For example, is it acceptable for a programmer in production to omit `self` when it is not necessary?

```
var name: String = ""

init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
}

func doSomeMethod() {
    print(name)
}
```

or should a developer in production *always* use the `self` clause when accessing instance properties in general like

```
var name: String = ""

init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
}

func doSomeMethod() {
    print(self.name)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently a [proposal on the swift-evolution repository](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0009-require-self-for-accessing-instance-members.md) to require `self` when accessing instance properties. It makes a fairly compelling argument for always requiring it.

Comment: I'm beginning to really like Swift's strictness. I feel like they should allow playgrounds to allow "lazy code" while real projects should conform to some "production code" standard

Comment: Note that the proposal was rejected in January.

Comment: @robmayoff, oops, I didn't even notice! D:

Comment: I just read the rational for the rejection, and my opinion has swayed. I suppose it only makes sense to use it when there's confusion for other instances. Otherwise, it's just clutter.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation describes it very well

> **The self Property**
>
> Every instance of a type has an implicit property called `self`, which
>   is exactly equivalent to the instance itself. You use the `self`
>   property to refer to the current instance within its own instance
>   methods.
>
> The `increment()` method in the example above *(see the example in the linked guide)* could have been written
>   like this:
>
> ```
> func increment() {
>   self.count += 1 
> }
> ```
>
> **In practice, you don’t need to write `self` in your code very often**.
>   If you don’t explicitly write `self`, Swift
>   assumes that you are referring to a property or method of the current
>   instance whenever you use a known property or method name within a
>   method. This assumption is demonstrated by the use of `count` (rather
>   than `self.count`) inside the three instance methods for `Counter`. *(`Counter` is a class mentioned in the section)*.
>
> The main exception to this rule occurs when a parameter name for an
>   instance method has the same name as a property of that instance. In
>   this situation, the parameter name takes precedence, and it becomes
>   necessary to refer to the property in a more qualified way. You use
>   the `self` property to distinguish between the parameter name and the
>   property name.

Source: [The Swift Language Guide: Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#)

Answer (score 2):

I am a big fan of always using ***this*** in production code.

It has no affect on the emitted machine code, and making things easier for programmers is pointless as opposed to making things easier for the variety 
of other tools you might want to use.  (i.e.  code searching tools, lint-type tools, and etc.)

Also, the time saved in avoiding stupid typo bugs is much greater than the time saved in typing.